# How to Read and Add Numbers from txt file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf, fgets

I am trying to make a program that reads numbers from a text file named **numbers.txt** that contains different numbers in each line.

For example:

```
8321
12
423
0
...
```

I have created this program, but it does not work properly.  I have tried many things and don't know what to do. Can someone guide me in the right direction?  Thank you!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char str[MAX_LEN];
    FILE *pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int num;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (!feof(pFile) && !ferror(pFile)) {
        if (fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num) == 1) {
            count++;
            while (strcmp(fgets(str, MAX_LEN, pFile), "\0") == 0) {
                printf("%s", str);
                //sum = sum + (int)(fgets(str, MAX_LEN, pFile));
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);

    printf("count = %d \n", count);
    printf("sum = %d \n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [c language : read file content as numbers and add them together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320335/c-language-read-file-content-as-numbers-and-add-them-together)

Comment: "but it does not work properly." lacks information.  What was the file contents, was was seen, what was expected?  A small example would help a lot.

Comment: As a stylistic nitpick, I'm opposed to the `pFile` – just call it `file`, no need to encode the pointerness in the variable name. IMO.

Comment: Just edited the question and gave an example of the .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp(fgets(str, MAX_LEN, pFile),"\0")` is wrong in many ways. For one, the argument of `strcmp` must be a string (which a null pointer isn't), but `fgets` returns `NULL` on error or end of file. You need to check that it didn't return `NULL` and then you can compare the string in `str`. However, there is no need to `strcmp` against `"\0"` (or, in this case equivalently, `""`) to detect the end of file, because that's when `fgets` returns `NULL`.

Another issue is that you are reading with both `fscanf` and `fgets` – pick one and stick with it. I recommend `fgets` since it's generally easier to get right (e.g., on invalid input it's a lot harder to recover from `fscanf` and make sure you don't get stuck in an infinite loop while also not losing any input). Of course you need to parse the integer from `str` after `fgets`, though, but there are many standard functions for that (e.g., `strtol`, `atoi`, `sscanf`).

Don't use `!feof(file)` as the loop condition (see, e.g., [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)). If you are reading with `fgets`, end the loop when it returns `NULL`.

Comment: To clarify, it's not incorrect as such to read with both `fscanf` and `fgets`, but it makes it harder to understand the program, especially if the input is more complicated. `fgets` is usually easier to get right, but admittedly in this case you could just `while (fscanf(pFile, " %d", &num) == 1) { sum += num; ++count; }`.

Comment: So when we do `fscanf` and it returns `1`, that means that there is a number in that line, and it stores that number into the variable `num`?

Comment: @MarkSantos Yes, `*scanf` functions return the number of items assigned, in this case you are only trying to read the one (`num`), so a return value of one means it succeeded. Anyway, you should always read the documentation of the functions you use, preferably set up your editor or IDE to display it for you automatically, and always check what the return values are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to split the numbers in each line, then using `atoi` function to convert string to `int`.

For example:

```
while(fgets(str, MAX_LEN, pFile)) { 
   // if the numbers are separated by space character
   char *token = strtok(str, " ");
   while(token != NULL) {
       sum += atoi(token);
       strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```

if there is only one number per line, you do not need to use `strtok`:

```
while(fgets(str, MAX_LEN, pFile)) { 
    sum += atoi(str);
    // OR
    sscanf(str,"%d\n", &new_number)
    sum += new_number;

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from the question that there would be more than one number per line. If there are, then `strtok` is good suggestion, but you are missing the assignment to `token` inside the inner loop.

Comment: Only one number per line. Example:
line 1: 812 
line 2: 4
line 3: 999
...

Comment: @Arkku i dont understand the missing that you were talking about ?

Comment: @Hitokiri The inner loop condition is `token != NULL` but you are not assigning `token` inside that loop, only before it. Anyway, it's irrelevant since the OP has confirmed that it's only one number per line.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has multiple problems:

- no test if a command line argument was passed.
- `while (!feof(pFile) && !ferror(pFile))` is always wrong to iterate through the file: `feof()` gives valid information only after a actual read attempt. Just test if the read failed.
- if `fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num) == 1)` add the number instead of just counting the numbers.
- `strcmp(fgets(str, MAX_LEN, pFile), "\0")` will fail at the end of the file, when `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

If the file only contains numbers, just read these numbers with `fscanf()` and add them as you progress through the file.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *pFile;
    int num
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Missing filename\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ((pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fscanf(pFile, "%d", &num) == 1) {
        sum += num;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(pFile);

    printf("count = %d \n", count);
    printf("sum = %d \n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```